# how to assign getting value to Radio button

Tags: java, android

I am getting some data like name,company,gender,age Through bundle.

And then i am assigning getting values to respective input controls like assigning name,company to edit Text.

But,question is how to assign getting gender (male or female )to Radio button.

```
String putName ,putGen ; 
putName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME"); 
empName.setText(putName); 
putGen = getIntent().getExtras().getString("GEN"); 
Here how to assign getting gender value to Radio Button
```

Comment: You check if its selected and get the value?

Comment: Hi Murat,      String putName ,putGen ;                                                   putName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME"); empName.setText(putName);                                                         putGen = getIntent().getExtras().getString("GEN");                        Here how to assign getting gender value to Radio Button

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
{
   maleRadiobutton.setChecked(true);
}else{
  femaleRadiobutton.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: i am getting NullPointerException. when i checked the button.

Comment: check whether you have initialized the radio button or not

Comment: i am implementing like this empFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
  empGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);int sel = empGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
  empMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(sel);
  
  emp.setListGen(empMale.getText().toString());
  list.add(emp);

Comment: i get Female the radio button is checked.but.when i get Male valu i got NullPointerException

Comment: change empMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(sel)
to empMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male)